# AWS Lambda unable to ping EC2 instance within VPC

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have an AWS Lambda function which is triggered by an S3 bucket. The Lambda function pings an EC2 instance inside a VPC. The VPC does not have a NAT. For some reason the Lambda is not able to connect to the EC2 and it is timing out. I have tried keeping the lambda both in the VPC and outside the VPC. I have also tried using the public and private IP of the instance but not seems to work. Any suggestions on what I could do next.
The  The code for the lambda function is as follows

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json
import boto3
import urllib2

print('Loading function')

s3 = boto3.client('s3')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    url = urllib2.urlopen("http://ip-address/API/")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, with the Lambda function inside the VPC, make sure you use the private IP of the EC2 instance. Then open port 80 in the EC2 instance's security group to allow incoming connections from anything belonging to the security group you assigned to the Lambda function.

Comment: Mark I have two questions:

One, should the lambda be within the VPC in which the EC2 is?

And second, how do we open port 80 for a security group? I have presently opened port 80 for certain IPs in my security group through which I access my EC2 instance. Do note that I do not want everyone to access my machine through HTTP.

Comment: Hey Mark,

Thanks for your answer. I had two questions for you.

First one, should the lambda function be within the VPC?

And the second one, I have presently opened port 80 for only certain IPs for my EC2 machine, how should I open the HTTP port 80 such that anything from within the security group of lambda can access the EC2?

Comment: Yes the Lambda function should be in the VPC, the same VPC that the EC2 instance is in. To open a port for a security group, when you are adding an inbound rule choose "Custom" for the source type, then enter the security group ID as the source value. If you start typing "sg" into this field it will pop up a list of your security groups.

Comment: private IP, that was it, woah, tried too many things before finding this post : ' )